# Concatenate audio files

Tags: audio, concatenation

I tried three different methods in order to concatenate songs

- Audacity: Works, but it adds a "click" sound between the first and
  second song
- cat command: I tried `cat *.wma > result.wma` and `cat second.wma >> first.wma`. Both have the same problem, the resulting file is just the
  first one.
- ffmpeg: `ffmpeg -i "concat:uno.wma|dos.wma" -acodec copy result.wma`, same problem as cat command, the file result.wma is a
  copy of uno.wma

Any help?

Comment: WMA files cannot be concatenated directly. You'd have to decode them into, say PCM WAV, then concatenate, then encode back to WMA.

Comment: I tried `ffmpeg -i song.wma song.wav` and then concatenate, still doesn't work

Comment: In principle, it should work. Try the other options listed [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate), either using the concat demuxer, or -- if that doesn't work -- directly concatenating the WMA files using the filter approach. If you could add the exact ffmpeg commands you're using, including the command line output, we can help you better.

Comment: Worked with the command `ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output` but it has the same problem as audacity now, it makes a "click" sound in the union of the two songs.

Comment: Did you add the WMA or WAV files to `mylist.txt`?

Comment: The files converted to WAV by using the command `ffmpeg -i song.wma song.wav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) tool? I typically use this to concatenate hundreds of .wav files at a time using `sox *.wav combined_audio.wav`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the waveforms it's difficult to say for sure, but if you are concatenating at points of supposed silence, then the best explanation for a click would be that one of more of the files has a bad DC offset. If you are doing it a a non-silent point, then you are almost certain to have a non-equal offset at that point.
The sudden transition between the two offsets is what you hear as a click.

The simplest fix would be to generate a short cross-fade between the two.

See - How to Geek : [How to Use Crossfade in Audacity for Seamless Transitions Between Audio Tracks](http://www.howtogeek.com/57252/how-to-use-crossfade-in-audacity-for-seamless-transitions-between-audio-tracks/) for how to achieve this [outside the scope of SE]